# jquery mobile autocomplete different behavior at loading page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-autocomplete

Currently I've a problem with the autocomplete function in jquery mobile ( http://andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/ ). So if I run the page directly via url, the page and the autocomplete functionality will work without any problems. If I navigate to the page via e.g. a mainmenu with the changepage function, the autocomplete function won't work!

Can you give me an advice?

My code:

mainmenu:

```
<li>
    <a id="buttonNewReservation" href="newReservations/newReservation.htm">Neue Reservation</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.cookie.json = true;
        $('#buttonNewReservation').click(newReservation);

        function newReservation() {
            var session = $.cookie("session");
            if (session != null) {
                $.mobile.changePage("/newReservations/newReservation.htm", 
                       {data:session});
            }
        }   
    </script>
</li>
```

- Page with autocomplete: The same code as in http://andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/search.html

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards, pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import the autocomplete script in the `head` tag. As JQM only loads this once (the first page you open) and then dynamically loads the `div` from the page you want to go to with `data-role="page"`, the head tag from the first page is always used in the pages you redirect to from that page.

For more information read this page:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html (Scripts & styles in the head)

So you need to add this line:

```
<script src="jqm.autoComplete-1.4.3-min.js"></script>
```

to you page div, like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
    <script src="jqm.autoComplete-1.4.3-min.js"></script>
    <div data-role="header">
    //rest of the code....
</div>//end of data-role="page"
```

This way the script will be loaded when JQM pulls in the page using AJAX and it will also be available when you go to the page directly